# jQuery not working in WebStorm

Tags: jquery, html, webstorm

So I'm trying to build a webapp and decided I will use jQuery. I'm working in WebStorm and have already downloaded the JavaScript libraries globally.

When typing WebStorm knows I'm using jQuery because it suggest jQuery input but when I go to run it in chrome nothing works except HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I used a simple `div` and made a block just to test jQuery but nothing. I'm hoping someone can tell me how to get it working in WebStorm or if I'm missing anything.

Comment: include more details to make your question clear and that will be helpful to others to answer.

Comment: this is my first post sorry, but include more details how? i think its clear jquery wont work in webstorm i need help making it work

Comment: jQuery is javascript, webstorm shouldn't have *anything* to do with why the library is not being loaded correctly. What does your link to jQuery look like ? Is there any errors in the console (developer tools in chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that JQuery is included in your HTML file via `<script>` tag. It must be either CDN link, like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`, or a link to the jquery.js file available locally (relative to your HTML file, like `<script src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>`.
JavaScript libraries configured in WebStorm are only used by WebStorm for completion, they aren't available to browser in runtime.